# Increase speed of PowerShell Get-ChildItem large directory

Tags: powershell, large-data, get-childitem

I have a script that references a `.csv` document of filenames and then runs a `Get-ChildItem` over a large directory to find the file and pull the 'owner'. Finally the info outputs into another `.csv` document. We use this to find who created files. Additionally I have it create `.txt` files with filename and timestamp to see how fast the script is finding the data. The code is as follows:

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path $serverPath -Filter $properFilename -Recurse -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' |
        Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(30) -and
                      $_.Extension -eq ".jpg"} |
        Select-Object -Property @{
            Name='Owner'
            Expression={(Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName).Owner}
          },'*' |
        Export-Csv -Path "$desktopPath\Owner_Reports\Owners.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
        $time = (get-date -f 'hhmm')
        out-file "$desktopPath\Owner_Reports\${fileName}_$time.txt"
}
```

This script serves it's purpose but is extremely slow based on the large size of the parent directory. Currently it takes 12 minutes per filename. We query approx 150 files at a time and this long wait time is hindering production.

Does anyone have better logic that could increase the speed? I assume that each time the script runs `Get-ChildItem` it recreates the index of the parent directory, but I am not sure. Is there a way we can create the index one time instead of for each filename?

I am open to any and all suggestions! If more data is required (such as the variable naming etc) I will provide upon request.

Thanks!

Comment: This has a large front-end load, but makes everything subsequent quite a bit faster: create an array of a recursive search, and perform all your searches against that so you're not constantly polling the directories for all the files.

Comment: I see a potential cause for slowdown: why are you looking for jpg in `Where-Object`?  Use `-Filter "$properFileName*jpg"`  Also, your logic for the lastwrite is wrong.  It should be `AddDays(-30)` otherwise you're looking into the future and it will always be true.  If you're on v3+, use the `-File` switch.

Comment: Thanks as always @TheIncorrigible1 , I will try to build out an array like you suggested.

Comment: Are you searching the same directory multiple times?  If not, the array is unnecessary

Comment: It is the same root directory ($serverPath), but the .jpgs will be several sub-directories deep (\\$serverPath\Dates\Sets\Output\*.jpg etc).

Comment: Yeah, even having the potentials into a single variable that you compare with will probably be faster.  `$arr = gci $serverPath; $names = $arr.Name; if ($names -contains $comparename) { etc }`

Comment: Using TheIncorrigible1's approach takes a snapshot of the directory which may be faster if the directory is constantly being updated with new or existing files.  Also, I wonder if logging a start time stamp when the script initializes and then using such to narrow your LastWriteTime filter (by including hours and minutes) may be beneficial.